# How Eclipse (IDE) can run main method in Java without a public class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a new project in Eclipse IDE, with only 1 class with the following code:

```
 class Test
 {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          System.out.println(44);
      }
 }
```

When I try to run, it prints the following:

> 44

As we know, the classes in which lies the main method, must be public.

Then how come eclipse can compile and even run this program?

Comment: "As we know, the classes in which lies the main method, must be public." This is just wrong. Clearly - you've demonstrated it not to be the case.

Comment: But I came across lots of tutorials online explain the non public classes cannot have main method. I assume that that standard has changed now? If yes then from which version of Java is it changed?

Comment: Please can you provide links to any of those tutorials? The tutorials might be wrong or out of date, but you might have misinterpreted them.

Comment: @user2015669 Perhaps the confusion is that the main method must be public, but the containing class can be package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are simply wrong:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

This is a quote from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) which points the oracle documentation.